# ' file_get_contents ' not working, don't understand why?

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

```
$mob_num=$_POST["mobileNumber"];
$sms_mes=$_POST["smsMessage"];

$lin_api = "http://abcd.com/SendSms.aspx?username=demo&password=demo123&to=$mob_num&from=TIWCOM&message=$sms_mes";
$get_mid = file_get_contents($lin_api);
echo " $get_mid ";
```

In the above code, I collect `mobileNumber` & `smsMessage` from a html form page and put it into `$lin_api` and try to send the `$lin_api` to abcd.com's server by `file_get_contents`

If I directly paste:

```
http://sitename/SendSms.aspx?username=demo&password=demo123&to=9876543210&from=TIWCOM&message=Testing SMS
```

(with '9876543210' as mobile number and 'Testing SMS' as message) in the link bar, it works. It sends SMS and returns a `messageid` code. But, if I use above code, I get some peculiar error message like:

```
Invalid Details (Username, Password, From, To or Message)
```

or

```
BAD Request. HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed
```

Why? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `$sms_mes = urlencode($_POST[smsMessage"]);` fix it?

Comment: Blankspaces are not allowed in the requested URI, if `urlencode` like Barmar said does not help, use `rawurlencode()`

Comment: Thanks [Barmar](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) it's working too but if I want to add `(by tiwcom)` after message and made the code `....&message=$sms_mes(by tiw.com);` I get Bad Request, HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed.- How can I add `(by tiwcom)` after message.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$lin_api = "http://abcd.com/SendSms.aspx?" .
    http_build_query(array('username' => 'demo',
                           'password' => 'demo123',
                           'to' => $mob_num,
                           'from' => 'TIWCOM',
                           'message' => "$sms_mes (by tiw.com)"));
```

Comment: Thanks [Barmar](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) it's working but if I want to add `(by tiwcom)` after message and made the code `'message' => $sms_mes(by tiw.com)));` I get syntax error like 'unexpected 'tiwcom' (T_STRING)'- How can I add `(by tiwcom)` after message.

Comment: `'message' => $sms_mes . ' by tiw.com')`

Comment: Updated the answer to show that. There's nothing special about putting a string after `=>`. If you want to concatenate or interpolate, just do it like you would in any other context.